# Accessing other entities from an EF Code-First POCO

Tags: .net, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first, poco

I have a data model which I've created using Entity Framework Code First POCO objects.

In one of my classes, I'd like to add a method 'GetUsefulInfo'.

In order to implement this method, I need to run queries against other entities in the data model.

The question is, how should I get hold of the data context from within this method? Do I need to pass it in as a parameter to the method? It feels like there should be a way to implement this without having to ask the consumers of this class do this?

Thanks,
- Chris

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a good fit for a `UserRepository`.

Generally the repository holds a reference to your context using some kind of dependency injection or just a private reference to your DataContext.

There you can query whichever repository to gather the required information.

Sample code:

```
public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    private readonly EntityFrameworkDataContext database =
                                                     new  EntityFrameworkDataContext();

    public User GetUserFullInfo()
    {
        try
        {
            // Your DataContext queries to return the User and all his info...
        }
        catch
        {
            // Whaterver...
        }
    }

}
```